# Draw inside UIImage of UIImageView xCode

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, xcode5

I'm having a simple draw tool, a UIImageView with AspectFit that isn't full window and UIImage inside ImageView. And following

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        _imageView2.image = _introImage2;
    }
    location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    lastClick = [NSDate date];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.imageView2];
    lastPoint.y -= 0;
    [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];

}
```

This work correct if UIImageView if full window. How to set UITouch only for UIImageView?

Comment: subclass UIImageView or find if the touch is on the UIIMageview in touceshBegan method.

Comment: but how to set to touch only 1 UIImageView

Comment: touch will be on both the view you have to check in condition if it is for UIImageview then do the rest of your work